# How to cache images in android?

Tags: android

In my android application,I am downloading images from the internet.

Now I want to store these images in cashe.
I also want to display images to users from cashe (not from internet again).

I cant use `CacheManager` class because its deprecated so i have to do this manually.
How can i do this?

Comment: You can store raw bytes of your images as files in SDCard, and later create bitmaps from those files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageManager to cache you images in android ,it provides performant and easy way to load image resources asynchronously with many options.Here is the website:http://code.google.com/p/android-image-manager/